# node poller not exiting properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I have a function that will poll a database ever x seconds. I am using the Q library so the function will return a promise. The function will ultimetly be used in a long chain of .then()s.

The function does give me the results that I expect but the function continues to run for 30-40 seconds after the results are returned. I cannot figure out why it would not exit right after I return.

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var pg = require('pg');
var Q = require('q');

connString = 'postgres://somedb_info';

var query = "SELECT * FROM job where jobid='somejobid123123'";

exports.run_poller = function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    function exec_query(callback) {
        pg.connect(connString, function(err, client, done) {
          if(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
          }
          client.query(query, function(err, result) {
            done();
            if(err) {
              return deferred.reject(err);
            }
            callback(result.rows[0]);
          });
        });
    }

    function wait_for(res){
        if(res.status == 'COMPLETE') {
          return deferred.resolve(res);
        } else {
            setTimeout(function(){
                exec_query(wait_for);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    exec_query(wait_for);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Just to test this I call the function from a main.js file like so:

```
var poller = require('./utils/poller').run_poller;

poller().then(console.log).catch(function(err) {console.log(err,'*');});
```

Why doesn't main.js exit right after the data is returned? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: My guess would be that some underlying system you're using (like the `pg` module) is using some timers and that is holding the app from exiting.  You may look in the `pg` module to see if you can tell it to "shutdown" or "close all connections" or something to tell it you're done with it.

Comment: I put client.end(); after the callback() and it seems to be exiting much earlier. But there is still about a 1-2 sec delay.

Comment: I see that pg maintains a connection pool.  I would assume that it's either taking awhile to time out some shared resources or it just takes a little while to shutdown.  You'll have to look into the pg library more if you want to figure out how to get it to shutdown quicker.  You make be able to just call `process.exit(0)` in your node app to force it to exit.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that is the reason. It is much quicker with the client.end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that pg maintains a connection pool. I would assume that it's either taking awhile to time out some shared resources or it just takes a little while to shutdown.

You may be able to just call `process.exit(0)` in your node app to force it to exit sooner if you know  you're done with all your work.

Or, you may be able to find configuration settings that affect how the connection pool works.

On [this doc page](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#parameterized-queries), there's an example like this that might help:

```
//disconnect client when all queries are finished
client.on('drain', client.end.bind(client));
```

You should read the [doc for `.end()`](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#end--null) to make sure you're using it correctly as there are some cases where it says it should not be called (though they may not apply if your done with all activity).